# Shibboleth Identity Server using External Shibboleth Identity Server for Authentication

Tags: shibboleth

I am designing a service to handle authentication across a number of hosted platforms. This service will need to be able to manage a number of different protocol for the users: LDAP, Shibboleth, no doubt others.

I was hoping to use the Shibboleth protocol internally and run the service as a Shibboleth IdP where depending on user category, nature of the protected resource, etc. the hard work of the authentication is passed on to the native LDAP, Shibboleth, or other server where the user already has an account.

It seems as though this should be possible, but I have not gotten sufficient clarity from the Shibboleth documentation to work out whether it is, let alone how to do it.

Is this possible? How do I do it? Useful documentation very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Shibboleth is not a protocol; it is the name of the software stak that uses the SAML protocol.

Shibboleth can authenticate users from LDAP, AD (and database via a JAAS plugin).

Documentation on hooking up Shibboleth to use LDAP for authentication and attribute retrieval is at: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/ResolverLDAPDataConnector

Comment: Thanks. But my question was about how to set up Shibboleth to use another Shibboleth Identity Provider as its authentication and attribute service for some classes of users.

Comment: If you read the documentation in the link above, it will give you the instructions :)

Comment: @user353829 There is a lot of documentation on that site, and the link you post is explicitly for ldap. For the sake of sanity, can you point to the specific Resolver you are talking about that allows Shibboleth to authenticate to another Shibboleth server?